# Adding Bootstrap to Blacklight

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, blacklight

I am creating a Rails application that will have the Blacklight gem installed. I need to customize the Blacklight interface by incorporating some Bootstrap stuff into it. However, it looks like Blacklight may have already incorporated a subset of Bootstrap into its source.

My question is... is it possible to add the full set of Bootstrap into my Rails application without completely breaking whatever Blacklight is using?

I'm kind of new to Rails and SCSS, so I don't really know if there's any sort of heirarchy, namespacing, etc.

Comment: what version of blacklight?

Comment: Which additional bootstrap module do you want to include as an example?

Comment: Well... I would like to add a tab panel... it doesn't seem to recognize any of the tab classes.

Comment: so I dropped a bootstrap 3 tab panel in a default blacklight, and found that you had to include bootstrap.js in the application's js assets, other than that it worked.  If you want to share your tab code in your question i can look a bit more.

Comment: Thanks Mike. If you want to submit that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Are you doing a Hydra project or just Blacklight? (more for my curiousity)

Answer (score 0):

I dropped a Bootstrap 3 tab panel in a default installation of blacklight, and found that you had to include bootstrap.js in the application's javascript assets, other than that it worked as expected.